# How to replace backslashes?

Tags: javascript, replace, backslash

Due to a single backslash I am not able to send the exact value to the server, so single backslashes need to be replaced with double backslashes in the script.

I use `replace` function as shown below but it doesn't work:

```js
str.replace(/\/g, "\\");
```

Can someone help me to find the right way?

Comment: you need to escape the \, so you need to double it up. it would be `/\\/` and `"\\\\"` Seems odd you would need to do this. Be better to show what your code is actually doing.

Comment: This very much sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)…

Comment: Also, are you sure you need regular expressions here? Nothing wrong with just replacing string literals with other string literals, unless yours is just a minimal example from a larger regular expression you are actually using.

Comment: Just because you add code to change what is sent to the server, doesn't mean the user cannot send things to the server anyway. If a single backslash breaks your server, **fix your server.**

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the backslash in both the regular expression and the replacing string. As [epascarello wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69469763/backslashes-replace-in-javascript#comment122943592_69469763), the following expression will work:

```js
str.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
```